# Grails 3/GORM - Log entry upon record change

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails3

I have the following User class:

```
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String email

    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName

    ...

}
```

I want to make a new domain object UserNameChange when the first, middle, or last name changes:

```
class UserNameChange {
    User user
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
}
```

I know I can do this in a transactional service, but it would be better if I could accomplish the same thing in the User class. How can I do this atomically? For instance, is "beforeUpdate" always done transactionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the domain class' methods are NOT transactional. So you would have to use `withTransaction()`:

```
class User {
  def beforeUpdate() {
    if( ![ 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName' ].any{ isDirty it } ) return 
    User.withTransaction{
      new UserNameChange( ... ).save()
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [audit plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/robertoschwald/audit-logging)

Comment: Wouldn't this only put UserNameChange's save in the transaction and not roll back if there was an error saving User?

Comment: No, it won't. You can check validity of the user object inside beforeUpdate

Comment: if you need a proper TX - use a service as you mentioned